# Extract network activities and their response headers without using selenium

Tags: python, http, request, response, grpc

I am trying to get the response body of this request "ListByMovieAndDate" from this specific website:
https://hkmovie6.com/movie/d88a803b-4a76-488f-b587-6ccbd3f43d86/SHOWTIME

Screenshot below is the request in Chrome Dev Tool.
[image]

I have tried several methods to mimic the request, including

1. copying the request as cURL (bash) and using [a tool](https://curl.trillworks.com/) to translate it to Python request

   ```
   import requests
   headers = {'authority': 'hkmovie6.com',
       'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"',
       'uthorization': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsImtpZCI6ImFjY2VzcyIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJtb3ZpZTYiLCJhdWQiOiJyb2xlLmJhc2ljIiwiZXhwIjoxNjI4MDg0NTUxLCJpYXQiOjE2MjgwODI3NTEsImp0aSI6IjQxZjJmZDBjLTk3YzgtNDFiYi04NDRiLTU5YWM5MTY0ZmYyNSJ9.jz_G80XDafzSHyzxog1IAY_xikAdQEEFizJXkiiHkNhwAY-MWF1E11Nel7WrsDlE184tcFtSjUKbHdx7281dFA',
       'x-grpc-web': '1',
       'language': 'zhHK',
       'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
       'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36',
       'content-type': 'application/grpc-web+proto',
       'accept': '*/*',
       'origin': 'https://hkmovie6.com',
       'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
       'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
       'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
       'referer': 'https://hkmovie6.com/movie/d88a803b-4a76-488f-b587-6ccbd3f43d86/SHOWTIME',
       'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-TW;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,ja;q=0.6',
       'cookie': '__stripe_mid=dfb76ec9-1469-48ef-81d6-659f8d7c12da9a119d; lang=zhHK; auth=%7B%22isLogin%22%3Afalse%2C%22access%22%3A%7B%22token%22%3A%22eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsImtpZCI6ImFjY2VzcyIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJtb3ZpZTYiLCJhdWQiOiJyb2xlLmJhc2ljIiwiZXhwIjoxNjI4MDg0NTUxLCJpYXQiOjE2MjgwODI3NTEsImp0aSI6IjQxZjJmZDBjLTk3YzgtNDFiYi04NDRiLTU5YWM5MTY0ZmYyNSJ9.jz_G80XDafzSHyzxog1IAY_xikAdQEEFizJXkiiHkNhwAY-MWF1E11Nel7WrsDlE184tcFtSjUKbHdx7281dFA%22%2C%22expiry%22%3A1628084551%7D%2C%22refresh%22%3A%7B%22token%22%3A%22eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsImtpZCI6InJlZnJlc2giLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJtb3ZpZTYiLCJhdWQiOiJyb2xlLmJhc2ljIiwiZXhwIjoxNjMwNjc0NzUxLCJpYXQiOjE2MjgwODI3NTEsImp0aSI6IjM0YWFjNWVhLTkwZTctNDdhYS05OTE3LTQ5N2UxMGUwNmU3YSJ9.Mrwt2iWddQHthQNHafF4mirU-JiynidiTzq0X4J96IMICcWbWEoZBB4M1HhvFdeB2WvU1nHaNDyMZEhkINKK8g%22%2C%22expiry%22%3A1630674751%7D%7D; showtimeMode=time; _gid=GA1.2.2026576359.1628082750; _ga=GA1.2.704463189.1627482203; _ga_8W8P8XEJX1=GS1.1.1628082750.11.1.1628083640.0',
   }
   data = '$\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000,\\n$d88a803b-4a76-488f-b587-6ccbd3f43d86\\u0010\\u0080\xB1\xA7\\u0088\\u0006'
   response = requests.post('https://hkmovie6.com/m6-api/showpb.ShowAPI/ListByMovieAndDate', headers=headers, data=data)
   ```

   All I got is a response header with a message: grpc: received message larger than max:

   > {'Content-Type': 'application/grpc-web+proto', 'grpc-status': '8',
   > 'grpc-message': 'grpc: received message larger than max (1551183920
   > vs. 4194304)', 'x-envoy-upstream-service-time': '49',
   > 'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://hkmovie6.com',
   > 'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
   > 'access-control-expose-headers': 'grpc-status,grpc-message',
   > 'X-Cloud-Trace-Context': '72c873ad3012ad710f938098310f7f11', ...
2. I also tried to use Postman Interceptor to capture the actual request sent when I browsed the site. This time with a different message:
   [image]

I managed to get the response body when I used selenium but it is far from ideal performance-wise.

I wonder if grpc is a hint but I spent several hours reading without getting what I wanted.

**My only question is whether it is possible to get the "ListByMovieAndDate" response just by making simple Python http request to the api url? Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

An admittedly cursory read suggests that the backend is gRPC and the client that you're introspecting is using [gRPC-Web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web) which is a clever solution to the problem of wanting to make gRPC requests using a JavaScript client.

Suffice to say that, you can't access the backend using HTTP/1 and REST if it is indeed gRPC but you may (!) be able to craft a [Python gRPC client](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/basics/) that talks to it **if** there's no constraints by e.g. client IP, type and there's no auth.